# base::identical() returns TRUE, but the data frames is different

Tags: r, character-encoding, dplyr

I've got a strange problem in `dplyr` (probably a bug?), but run into an even more strange problem when debugging.

The dplyr-part of code does [already have an issue now](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1404), but please help me figure out why `identical()` doesn't detect differences?

The code (copied from the issue i created on dplyr's github) show the issue with swedish letters (å,ä,ö,Å,Ä,Ö), and as a result of that an example when `base::identical(x,y)` returns `TRUE` even when dataframe x and y are different.

```
# Script to show how dplyr::select() breakes dplyr::group_by() with swedish names
library(dplyr)

# Create data frame, column 1's name contains ä (specific swedish letters are åäöÅÄÖ)
my_df <- data.frame(användarnamn = letters[1:4], my_numvalues = 1:4, 
                my_text = c("stop","break","my","code"),
                extra_col = LETTERS[1:4])

# use dplyr::select() to subset columns, then dplyr::group_by
# group_by fails on swedish column names if the df is subsetted with filter.
# If not subsetted or subsetted with [,1:3], everything works

my_df %>% select(1:3) %>% group_by(my_numvalues)   # This works
my_df %>% select(1:3) %>% group_by(användarnamn)   # This fails
my_df[,1:3] %>% group_by(användarnamn)             # This works
my_df %>% group_by(användarnamn)                   # This works

# Same thing, but step by step
my_df_selected <- select(my_df, 1:3)
group_by(my_df_selected, användarnamn)             # This fails
group_by(my_df_selected, my_numvalues)             # This works

# and by %>% 
my_df_selected %>% group_by(användarnamn)          # This fails
my_df_selected %>% group_by(my_numvalues)          # This works

# The names of the orignal df and the filtered is identical
identical(names(my_df)[1:3],names(my_df_selected))
# The function base::make.names() doesn't change the name, it's already valid
identical(names(my_df_selected), make.names(names(my_df_selected)))

# copy to a new df to rename
my_df_selected_renamed <- my_df_selected
# rename the df with it's own old names passing make.names()
names(my_df_selected_renamed) <- make.names(names(my_df_selected_renamed))

# The orignal subsetted and the renamed df is identical
# according to base::identical()
identical(my_df_selected, my_df_selected_renamed)

# Here's the strange thing, it works now! Why??? I REALLY don't understand!
my_df_selected_renamed %>% group_by(användarnamn)  # This works now!

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    R6_2.1.1        assertthat_0.1        parallel_3.2.2 
[6] DBI_0.3.1       tools_3.2.2     Rcpp_0.12.1
```

Comment: What version of dplyr are you using, because this all seems to run fine for me under 0.4.3.

Comment: Help page to `identical` says "Character strings are regarded as identical if they are in different marked encodings but would agree when translated to     UTF-8.". My candidate for your problems. See `Encoding(names(my_df_selected))` and `Encoding(make.names(names(my_df_selected)))`.  And btw: `sessionInfo()` is always helpful.

Comment: @joran I'm also running 0.4.3. Strange... Did you copy my code so you get the swedish letter 'ä' in användarnamn column?

Comment: Added sessionInfo() to my question. I also got the same result when I run a rstudio-session in amazon EC2.  Image from http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/

Comment: I did copy the code so that I had the non-English characters. My best guess is that this is related to the locale you're running R under, as I'm in `en_US.UTF-8`.